# asynctask freezes UI for time of thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Iam doing a refresh button for Monitoring Cars App, so when i click on it it freezes the UI for secs of threads given and when i decrease the time, it won't get the data properly (zero or null data)

Click Listener:

```
refreshcount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public synchronized void run() {
                    if (conDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                        unitsRefreshTask = new AsyncRefreshUnit(
                                MonitoringController.usernamei,
                                MonitoringController.passwordi);
                        unitsRefreshTask.execute();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            //wait(11000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            MyApplication.Logs(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())+getClass().toString()+" refreshcount.onclick() when calling AsyncRefreshUnit"+"\n"+e.getMessage().toString());
                        }

                    } else if (!conDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                        showNoNet();
                    }
                }
            });     

            source = new CarsDataSource(getApplicationContext());
            source.open();

            MonitoringController.cars.clear();
            MonitoringController.cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
            ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();


            System.out.println("task.getResult().size(); >>"
                    + unitsRefreshTask.getResult().size());
            carList = (ArrayList<Car>) unitsRefreshTask.getResult();
            System.out.println("carList >>" + carList.size());


            for (int u = 0; u < carList.size(); u++) {
                System.out.println("carList.size() : >" + carList.size());
                MonitoringController.cars.add(carList.get(u));
                System.out.println("size"
                        + MonitoringController.cars.size());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < carList.size(); i++) {
                SerialExist = source.isExistRoleAndSerial(getApplicationContext(),carList.get(i).getRoute_Nmae(),carList.get(i).getSerialNumber());
                if(SerialExist){
                    source.updateInfoByroleName(getApplicationContext(),carList.get(i));
                }else if(!SerialExist){
                    source.createCar(carList.get(i));
                }
                // System.out.println("update is >>" + update);
            }

            MonitoringController.countOfUnits = source.getCountsOfUnits(
                    getApplicationContext(), MonitoringController.routname);
            Log.e("C_InformationScreen.class",  source.getCountsOfUnits(
                    getApplicationContext(), MonitoringController.routname)+"");
            ((TextView) numOfUnits)
            .setText(source.getCountsOfUnits(
                    getApplicationContext(), MonitoringController.routname) + " Units");
            ((TextView) numOfUnits)
            .setText(carList.size() + " Units");



            source.close();
        }
    });
```

AsyncTask:

```
public class AsyncRefreshUnit extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Car>> {
    String user, pass, resultstring;
    ArrayList<Car> result = new ArrayList<Car>();
    int count;

    public List<Car> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(ArrayList<Car> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public AsyncRefreshUnit(String user, String pass) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Car> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
            initList();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void finish(ArrayList<Car> result) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            onCancelled(result);
        } else {
            onPostExecute(result);
        }
        Status mStatus = Status.FINISHED;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        dialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {     
        dialog =  ProgressDialog.show(C_InformationScreen.this,"","Refreshing Units Data  ..");
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Car> doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(
                    InternetActions.getHttpParameters(110000), 70000); 
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                    "http://trackmonitor.net/software/AndroidControl.aspx?UserName="
                            + user + "&PassWord=" + pass + "&Action=Units");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                int responsecode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (responsecode == 200) {
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    resultstring = MonitoringController.convertinputStreamToString(in);
                    try {
                        JSONArray plates = new JSONArray(resultstring);
                        // MyAssmts.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < plates.length(); ++i) {
                            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) plates.get(i);
                            result.add(convertToCar(jo));
                            Log.v("check on adding car_id to list", result.get(i)
                                    .getCarId() + "");
                            Log.v("check on adding car_name to list", result.get(i)
                                    .getName());
                            Log.v("check on adding car_serial to list",
                                    result.get(i).getSerialNumber());
                            Log.v("check on adding car_device to list",
                                    result.get(i).getDeviceId());
                            Log.v("check on adding car_phone to list", result
                                    .get(i).getPhone());
                            Log.v("check on adding car_role to list", result.get(i)
                                    .getRoute_Nmae());
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException  c) {
                        Log.v("Exception >>>", c.getMessage().toString());
                        c.printStackTrace();
                        MyApplication.Logs(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())+getClass().toString()+"AsyncRefreshUnit.doInBackground.JSONException "+"\n"+c.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                    long total = 0;
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    while ((count = in.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                        // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                        setProgress((int)((total*100)/1000));
                    }
                }else if(responsecode != 200){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your connection is break down please check your connection ..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                MyApplication.Logs(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())+getClass().toString()+"AsyncRefreshUnit.doInBackground.ClientProtocolException "+"\n"+e.getMessage().toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your connection is break down please check your connection ..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your connection is break down please check your connection ..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (e.getMessage().indexOf("Connection reset by peer") > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "please Connect again ..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    MyApplication.Logs(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())+getClass().toString()+"AsyncRefreshUnit.doInBackground.IOException "+"\n"+e.getMessage().toString());

                }
            }               
            return result;
        } catch (Exception t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            MyApplication.Logs(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())+getClass().toString()+"AsyncRefreshUnit.doInBackground.Exception "+"\n"+t.getMessage().toString());

        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                    if (httpClient != null)
                        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                } catch (IOException x) {
                    Log.e("Exception > ",  x.getMessage().toString());
                    MyApplication.Logs(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())+getClass().toString()+"AsyncRefreshUnit.doInBackground when closing connection "+"\n"+x.getMessage().toString());

                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple search on "UI freezes" reveals the mistake that you and so many others make:

**DO NOT SLEEP OR WAIT ON UI THREAD!!!**

Why did you even get the idea that it's OK to do so? That's what *background* threads are for. Need to wait a bit and then do something with UI? *Use a Timer!* Need to do something in a loop with delays? *Use a Timer!* Need to process a large task that can take up more than a couple hundred millies? *Use a background task!*

What you did is literally the first thing any tutorial on UI concurrency says NOT to do.

**EDIT**

After looking at your code a bit more, I'm puzzled at what that sleep is supposed to do anyway. It's *after* you started the `AsyncTask` execution, hence it doesn't really delay *anything* except redraws. You probably wanted to put it *into the background* thread to delay execution or result publishing or smth.